# Iterate through Multiple Lists and assign Variables based on each iteration

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a csv with 4 columns which I convert to a pandas dataframe, and then make each column a list.
I'm trying to iterate over each list and extract data based on an ID.
Depending on what kind of ID it is, it will select from 1 of 2 dropdowns.
I'm trying to work out the logic of setting a sale_type variable and form_code variable to be different for each iteration of a column.

With the code below it automatically sets form_code = 2 and the sale_type ='Push Notification'
after finished iterating through the push notification column it returns form_code = 1 and sale_id to Nan
and then stops.

The Push Notification sale_id list is the last list and should be iterated through last.

````
def get_report_data(self):
        ("Gathering Report Data...")
        current_date = helpers.currentDate
        report_results = []
        data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rford\Desktop\sale_ids.csv')
        everyone_ids = data['Everyone'].tolist()
        dd_ids = data['Daily Deal'].tolist()
        targeted_ids = data['Targeted'].tolist()
        push_ids = data['Push Notification'].tolist()
        for sale_id, sale_id, sale_id, sale_id in zip(everyone_ids, dd_ids, targeted_ids, push_ids):
            if sale_id in everyone_ids:
                form_code = 1
                sales_type = "Everyone"
            elif sale_id in dd_ids:
                form_code = 1
                sales_type = "Daily Deal"
            elif sale_id in targeted_ids:
                form_code = 2
                sales_type = "Targeted"
            else: 
                form_code = 2
                sales_type = "Push Notification"
            helpers.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form[{}]/div/select/option[@value={}]'.format(form_code, sale_id)).click()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'for' loop will throw away everything except the last list.  Remember the zip delivers one thing from each list in every loop.  There's no shame in doing this as 4 separate 'for' loops, but if you really want to, you can do:

```
    for form_code, sales_type, idlist in (
        ( 1, "Everyone", everyone_ids ),
        ( 1, "Daily Deal", dd_ids ),
        ( 2, "Targets", targeted_ids ),
        ( 2, "Push Notification", push_ids ) ):
        for sale_id in idlist:
            helpers.driver.find_element_by_xpath( ... etc ... )
```